# Declare variable, whose type has an deleted default constructor, without a value

Tags: c++, default-constructor, variable-declaration

I want to initialize a variable in multiple if-else branches, to use it later, basically like this:

```
Foo foo;

if (someCondition) {
    std::string someString = getTheString();
    // do some stuff
    foo = Foo(someString);
} else {
    int someInt = getTheInt();
    //do some other stuff maybe
    foo = Foo(someInt);
}

// use foo here
```

Unfortunately in this example the type `Foo` has a deleted default constructor, so the code above doesn't compile. Is there a way to initialize such a variable in this manner?

**EDIT:**

As you can see in my Example, I'm using different constructors and also do other things in the if/else blocks, so unfortunately the ternary operator doesn't work.
If there is no way, without `foo` being a pointer, I could obviously take a different approach, but I was curious, if my approach somehow worked.

Comment: If it's no more complicated than that, `Foo foo(someCondition ? someValue : otherValue)`. If it is more complicated, you need to add more details.

Comment: *It is not possible for me, that foo could be a pointer, so this solution is ruled out.* Why?  That's the idiomatic way to handle this.

Comment: @NathanOliver that was a bad formulation on my side, I'm sorry. It would make things easier, if `foo` wasn't a pointer, because it is stored afterwards in a form, where I cannot do manual memory management and a smart pointer would also not be easy to handle in my scenario.

Comment: @JosefZoller "a smart pointer would also not be easy to handle in my scenario" does not make much sense, you will need to elaborate. It's not much different having `unique_ptr<Foo> foo;` than `Foo foo;`, you can use a reference to give a nice name if you like

Comment: @M.M that means, If there was no way to do what I wanted without pointers, then I could find a solution, that bypasses the whole problem. Therefore my question was basically *Is there a way to do this as I wanted to do?*.

Comment: You can't have `Foo foo;` and there are several alternatives as have been covered in answers but you keep saying  you don't like them for reasons you can't explain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't told us *why* you can't use a pointer ... but, in the meantime, here's is a solution that ostensibly is pointer-free:

```
#include <optional>    
std::optional<Foo> foo;

if (someCondition) {
    std::string someString = getTheString();
    // do some stuff
    foo.emplace(someString);
} else {
    int someInt = getTheInt();
    //do some other stuff maybe
    foo.emplace(someInt);
}
if (foo.has_value()) { /* use foo here */ }
```

---

If you have a coding standard or something that prohibits the use of *raw* pointers (and `new`), then you can use `std::unique_ptr`.

```
#include <memory>
std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo;

if (someCondition) {
    std::string someString = getTheString();
    // do some stuff
    foo = std::make_unique<Foo>(someString);
} else {
    int someInt = getTheInt();
    //do some other stuff maybe
    foo = std::make_unique<Foo>(someInt);
}
if (foo) {/* use foo here */}
```

---

You could also put your `Foo`-creation logic in a separate function (or lambda):

```
auto getFoo(/* ... */) {
    if (someCondition) {
        std::string someString = getTheString();
        // do some stuff
        return Foo(someString);
    } else {
        int someInt = getTheInt();
        //do some other stuff maybe
        return Foo(someInt);
   }
}
// ...
Foo foo = getFoo(/*...*/);
// use foo here
```

Comment: note that the `optional` version requires the object to be copy/move-constructible

Comment: @M.M: No, it doesn't. It only requires that if you actually copy/move the `optional`. Or if you try to assign a `T` to the `optional` instead of using `emplace`.